# Fix Minimal BASH like line editing is supported GRUB Error In Linux

Tags: grub2, grub-efi

Followed this tutorial but got no success- https://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/
Here is a link to pastebin - http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/H6CJ5CPPBH/

I've dual booted my system with Windows 10 Pro and Ubuntu MATE.
This problem suddenly started. Please help guys. 
I've dual booted both Windows and Ubuntu in UEFI mode and my hardisk type is GPT which I chose during booting my pen drive using Rufus.

Guys please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: Simplest method is to boot a live disc/USB and run `boot-repair`